# php httpresponce to android is always resulting with the same result while database is changing

Tags: java, php, android, database

I have this `RegisterActivity.java` where the user registers username and password, when the user presses `ok` I am always getting the dialog containing `user already exists` while the user doesn't exist and it is added successfully to the database.

here is the code of `RegisterActivity.java`

```
        package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;


    public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;
    EditText et,pass;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);

                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Register();
                        }
                      }).start();               
            }
        });

    }

    void Register(){
        try{            

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.112/RegisterConnectNow.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);


            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

                dialog.dismiss();
                    showAlertSuccess(); 
            }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
                dialog.dismiss();
                showAlertError();
            }
            else{
                dialog.dismiss();
                displayToast("error");
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            dialog.dismiss();
            showAlertInternet();
        }

    }
    public void showAlertSuccess(){

        RegisterActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Success")
                        .setMessage("User Added Successfully")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

            }
        });

    }
    public void showAlertError(){

        RegisterActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("User Already exists")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

            }
        });

    }
    public void showAlertInternet(){

        RegisterActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("No Connection to the server")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.register, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void displayToast(String s){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and here is the php code of `RegisterConnectNow.php`

```
 <?php
require_once 'DatabaseConnectNow.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query_search = "select * from userstable where username = '".$username."'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query
_exec);

 if($rows == 0) { 
 $query = "INSERT INTO userstable (username,password)
                    VALUES ('$username', '$password')";

            mysql_query($query);

            echo "1";

 }
 else  {
    echo "2"; 
}
?>
```

So My code is behaving **Correctly** with respect to the database , users are added when they are not duplicate and not added when they already exist. The problem is that the response is always returning as `2` so it is displaying `user already exists`

Comment: Are you sure? Remove the code where you insert the user and empty the database. Does it still say it already exists?

Comment: if I remove the INSERT code Everything works correctly and it displays `user added successfully` with responce `1` , so what is the problem here ?

Comment: I tried adding a user manually to the database and tried again it responded correctly and said `user already exists` and when I use a user not existing it says `user added successfully` so everything is good when I removed the INSERT code, but how to insert to the database now